# AS3 - How to strip last part of the string?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash

```
A random string.
A random string 2.

<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>    
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

What I want to do?

- Strip off the hosting24 analytics code
- Divide the string into different strings based on the line breaks, so that the `A random string.` and `A random string 2.` are two different strings.

How do I achieve this in ActionScript3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lines:Array = str.split("\n");
```

You can ignore the extra lines, or you can slice:

```
var twoLines:Array = lines.slice(0,2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how I will remove the hosting analytics code?